# How to access an object in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, object-tag

I have created an object using the object tag as below:

```
< object id="video1" classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
        codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
        width="640" height="480"  >               
        < /object >
```

I want to access this in the code behind in the .aspx.cs,but currently it is inaccessible.How should this be done?

Answer (score 2):

you can add attribute `runat="server"` to your object to get it accessible from code behind.

**EDIT:** You need to remove the extra `clsid` value in the `classid` parameter value.

Try This:

```
<object id="video1" runat="server" classid="9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"
 codebase="http://downloads.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/latest/win32/axvlc.cab"
 width="640" height="480"></object>
```

Comment: I did this but I got the error GUID should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes.

Comment: @TVicky: check my eidt , you need to remove the `clsid:` in classid